# Silverlight ListPicker - Default Selection

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listpicker

I am building a WP7 application using Silverlight. This application includes a Page that makes use of the ListPicker. This ListPicker has data that is bound to it via my Page's view-model. The ListPicker displays the options correctly. However, the display looks odd.

When the options initially load, the first option appears selected. This selected item looks to be several pixels off from the top and the left. If I open-and-close the ListPicker, it looks as intended.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does any have any ideas how to overcome this? I attempted setting a binding on the SelectedIndex and SelectedValue properties, but this did not work.

Thank you!

Comment: have you got a custom template applied to the ListPicker?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SL ListPicker works under the assumption that there is always an active selection as long as it is bound to a non-empty dataset. Not sure if you can override this behavior; but seems like your problem is that the selected item looks awkward. Anyway you can adjust the template? Also, please see this [post](http://samidipbasu.com/2011/05/19/fun-with-toolkit-listpicker-selections/) to make sure you are not caught off-guard with the SelectionChanged event.

Hope this helps!